# Exception Error in my Magento home page: client denied by server configuration

Tags: magento-1.7, template, layout, error, nvp-gateway-error

I am getting an error message when I am hitting my Magento home page URL. The error message is:

> There has been an error processing your request
>
> Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.
>
> Error log record number: 1106250235

I have checked the error log and there I am getting the error message as

```
client denied by server configuration: C:/wamp/www/magento-new/app/etc/local.xml
```

Comment: what is the "home page URL"? and are you using IIS webserver?

Comment: I mean to say any URL of magento (Any page).

Comment: ya I know.. what is that URL in your case? and what is the webserver you are using? please mention those details in your post.

Comment: I am using WAMP server . I am hitting localhost/magento/index.php

Comment: looks like you haven't started the mysql through wamp.

Comment: My SQL is started and its running properly. And one more thing the website was running properly before few hours , but just  from before sometime I am getting this message. I guess there is some problem with my newly created theme but could not get what could be the problem.Because if i use some different theme the problem doesn't exist.

Comment: There should be a file generated in var/report/1106250235 with an error message. Post that and we can give you more info.

Comment: Can you please tell how can i attach a file in order to post var/report/1106250235 file?

Comment: @AkashGoswami use http://www.ideone.com

Comment: please find the var/report/1106250235 file at URL http://ideone.com/as3fQa

Comment: is there any changes done by you?

Comment: No Changes made by me.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the report file, I can conclude that somewhere in your layout files there is this line of code

```
<action method="selabetElementClass"....
```

that most probably should be

```
<action method="setLabelElementClass"....
```

If it's not in the layout files then it could be in the `Layout updates` field of your home page in `CMS->Pages` in the backend.

Answer (score 1):

this always happen when you try to query database with error in your query syntax so try to review your last steps or delete the last changes you do before down and it will return back on , also if you have any backup for the files it will be more good to handle this issue